# Why is Annalise Keating scared to death about her adoption secret being revealed?

Tags: plot-explanation, how-to-get-away-with-murder

I am watching the fifth season of  *How to get away with murder*. I am a bit lost with why Annalise Keating and her allies (students and friends) are worried about her adoption secret being revealed.

I remember it was about Sam's adoption but unable to remember why this has to be a big secret. I understand it can be used against her but why and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, then Annalise never told the police about the fact that she knew Wes before he became her student. Releasing that information may lead to reopening of Sam and Wes cases because as of know Wes is considered to be some crazy pupil of hers.

If papers are released then it might become evident that she acted as a mother figure to Wes in all these years; tried to adopt him, got him into the school; made him a part of Keating-5 and then thought of a plan to kill her husband via him.

Comment: Of particular note is the last half of the final season (spoilerish) where Annalise is specifically being tried as having ordered her students to kill Sam (among others) for her. Annalise being maternally inclined to Wes supports that claim.